# Where did the heiltsuk's find obsidian?

Tags: earth-history, archaeology

The discovery of hearths and other carbon dated items on an island off the north east coast of Canada puts modern humans there 2,000 years before the Alaskan land bridge existed.  The glaciers of North America would have prevented the west to east traverse at this time.  They had obsidian tools.  Where did they get it?  Where were they from?

Comment: i googled obsidian canada this is the first of 9milion hits http://www.sourcecatalog.com/canada/s_canada.html

Comment: Curious about the mention of the Heiltsuk in relation to the text below.  The Heiltsuk nation is located on the North West Canadian coast, not the North East coast.  There are sources of obsidian in BC but not to the same extent as is found further south in Washington or Oregon states.  The coastal aboriginal groups had extensive trade routes with the groups further to the south and likely got some obsidian cores through these trade routes.